# Disable bounce in Postfix after failed mail forwarding

Tags: postfix, email-bounces, plesk

I have some mailboxes in Plesk/Postfix that redirect to some external addresses. If Postfix fails to forward a message to these addresses, it bounces back to the original sender, who is a fake address most of the time.
How to completely disable bounces ?
I know this is bad but the actual behavior is worst.

My master.cf already has the line "bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       discard" with DISCARD keyword and it doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Don't use fake sender. If you don't want to receive bounces for particular user, create it as alias for /dev/null

Comment: I was talking about incoming mails ... I can't control the sender addresses of incoming mail. Then the mail is forwarded to some gmail or yahoo address of our customer, it fails because it's spam, and a NDR is sent back to the original spammer or victim. That's what I want to avoid.

Comment: Then enable more strict verification for incoming email, see http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_VERIFICATION_README.html#forged_sender

Comment: That doesn't help me. I want to disable all bounces.

Comment: Then expect to have your mail server to be banned by major email providers, as you are forwarding spam messages to them.

Comment: My server is already blacklisted, thank you. We have several issues to solve, filtering is one of them. Nobody can help about bounces ? :'-(

Comment: Hi antares, 

as already mentioned, you will not solve your issue by switching of your bounce - eMails. 
Pls. consider to visit the Plesk Community Forum at => https://talk.plesk.com , so that experienced server administrators may help you to solve your misconfiguation for your main.cf + master.cf , in order to secure your mail - server on a server with Plesk installed. ;-)

Comment: Even with filtering, there will always be some spam that get to the mailbox. And trigger a bounce once the forwarding fails. It is not a problem for me and my customer to disable bounces, even for ham. The risk is okay. But I see you think I'm stupid and you're smarter than me. Or maybe you just don't know the answer to my original question ;)